# Get week start date(Monday or Sunday) from week number of the month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have data that has date column in this format `'Mar Wk 4 2022'`, where Mar signifies the month that is 'March', 'Wk 4' signifies the week of the month (values ranging from 1 to 5) and '2022' signifies the year,

is there a way to get week start date (Monday) of that week, i.e.,. 4th week of March, 2022?

Comment: What do you mean by 'week of the month'?  Is that 1st-7th is week 1, 8th-14th is week 2 etc?  If so, It'll depend purely on the day of the 1st of the month so if it's 'Monday', the result will be week * 7 - 6.  If it's Tuesday, it'll be 'week * 7', Wednesday will be 'week * 7 - 1' etc.  How you determine the day of the 1st will depend on numpy's functionality that I'm not familiar with but if it returns 'Mon' etc. you can index a list ["Tue","Wed","Thu"...] and subtract the result from week * 7.  Perhaps I should have made this an answer rather than a comment!

Comment: what is your definition of "week number of the month"? E.g. is the first week of the month the week that the first day of the month falls in?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `' Mon'` (for Monday) to your strings, and convert using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with the [`%b Wk %U %Y %a`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) format:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']+' Mon', format='%b Wk %U %Y %a')
```

output:

```
            date start_date
0  Mar Wk 4 2022 2022-01-24
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Mar Wk 4 2022']})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there seems to be a misunderstanding, the week number given  is week of the month, which will have values from 1 to 5, "%U" means week number of the year right? Answer should be "2022-03-21" right 4th week of March, 2022. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @harshavardhan I just realized that, apologies. Week of month is no so simple, let me see if I can find out (but not right now!)

Comment: how do you define the week of month? for example in Jan 2022, what would be the first week? Sat 1st to Sun 2nd, then second week Mon 3rd to Sun 8th? (in which case we count 6 weeks in January 2022) Or rather 1st week Sat 1st to Fri 7th?

Answer (score 0):

If 'week' of the month is:

```
week 1:  1st - 7th
week 2:  8th - 14th
etc.
```

it'll depend purely on the day of the 1st of the month so if it's 'Monday', the result will be week * 7 - 6. If it's Tuesday, it'll be 'week * 7', Wednesday will be 'week * 7 - 1' etc.

I don't know numpy, but assume you can get the day as 'Tue' etc. given a day, month and year.  So, with appropriate variables the answer is...

```
monday = week * 7 - ["Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon"].index(day)
```